# Determining if $m$ can be written as a combination of distinct powers of $w$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Given a weight $m$ and weights $w^0, w^1, w^2, \ldots, w^{100}$, determine if $m$ can be measured on a balance using these weights. In other words, is it possible to place a weight $m$ and some weights on the left pan of a scale, and some other weights on the right pan of the scale such that the pans of the scale were in balance?

This is an interesting question I found in my book.

I tried to convert $m$ into base $w$. If all bits are $0$ or $1$, then we can simply place the weight $m$ on the left side, and the corresponding weights on the right side of the scale.

But how do we solve the other case? (The case where we can have some masses on the left side of the scale)

Comment: You have exactly one of each weight?

Comment: Yes. We can't use a weight more than once.

Comment: Notice that depending on whether you place the $w^k$ on the same side, on the opposite side, or not on the scale at all, you have the following representation: $$ m = \sum_{i=0}^{100} \delta w^k $$

where $\delta\in\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: @Vepir Yes I get that. How do we proceed? How do we know if there exists such a combination of $w$'s so that $m = \sum_{i=0}^{100} \delta w^i$ ?

Comment: Check that the  number $m$ has only digits $\{-1,0,1\}$  in the "offset number base" $\overline{w}$  whose digits are $\{-1,0,1,2,3,\dots,w-2\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which side of the scale some $w^k$ is (or is not), your number is represented as:

$$
m=\sum_{k=0}^{100}\delta\cdot w^k,\text{ }\delta\in\{-1,0,1\}
$$

> This is possible if and only if number $m$ has only digits $\{-1,0,1\}$ in "offset number base $\overline{w}$".

We define the "offset number base $\overline{w}$" as a base with digits $\{-1,0,1,2,3\dots,w-2\}$.

In comparison, a "standard number base $w$" has digits $\{0,1,2,3,4,\dots,w-1\}$.

Let $(-1)=\overline{1}$ be a notation for our negative one digit.

---

*How to convert a number to base $\overline{w}$*?

Notice that the digits of $m$ in base $w$ are simply the remainders of division of $m$ by $w$.

To get $\overline{w}$ digits instead of $w$ digits, simply treat the remainder $m\equiv(w-1)$ as $m\equiv(-1)$ instead, where we can write $(-1)=\overline1$.

To get the first digit, observe $m\pmod{w}=m_1\in\{0,1,2,\dots,w-1\}$ where $(w-1)\equiv(-1)$.

Now repeat the process on $(m-m_1)/w$ to get the second digit $m_2$, and so on.

---

*For example,*

Lets convert the number $m=293$ to "offset base" $\overline{w}$ for $w=7$.

$293\pmod7\equiv 6\equiv -1$ so the units digit is $m_1=-1$. The next number is $(293-\overline{1})/7=42$.

$42\pmod7\equiv 0$ so the next digit is $m_2=0$. The next number is $(42-0)/7=6$.

$6\pmod7\equiv 6\equiv -1$ so the next digit is $m_3=-1$. The next number is $(6-\overline{1})/7=1$.

$1\pmod7\equiv 1$ so the next digit is $m_4=1$. The next number is $0$, so we are done.

We got that $293$ has digits $(1,\overline1,0,\overline1)=(1,-1,0,-1)$ in base $\overline{w}=\overline7$, hence it is possible.

---

*Remark.* For $w=3$ this is also called [Balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary). - see [Find algorithm for converting number to Balanced ternary](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570631/318073).

Comment: And of course watch out that the largest weight used is $w^{100}$. (Number of digits in base $\overline{w}$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that avoids actually converting to base $w$, although it accomplishes the same result. It involves serially looking at $m$ or a number derived from $m$ according to the modulus $w$.

Create a list with three categories: positive, discard, negative.

Compute $m \bmod w$. If that residue is other than $-1,0,1$, stop. The problem has no solution. If the residue is $-1$, write $w^0$ in the negative category. If the residue is $0$, write $w^0$ in the discard category. If the residue is $1$, write $w^0$ in the positive category.

Compute $m_1=\frac{m-(m \bmod w)}{w}$, and compute $m_1 \bmod w$. If that residue is other than $-1,0,1$, stop. The problem has no solution. If the residue is $-1$, write $w^1$ in the negative category. If the residue is $0$, write $w^1$ in the discard category. If the residue is $1$, write $w^1$ in the positive category.

Compute $m_2=\frac{m_1-(m_1 \bmod w)}{w}$, and compute $m_2 \bmod w$.

Continue as before, placing $w^k$ in a category according to the residue of $m_k$, if you do not encounter a stop at some step. Terminate the algorithm when ${m_k-(m_k \bmod w)}=0$

If we call numbers in the negative category $w^j$ and numbers in the positive category $w^i$, it will be true that $m=\sum(w^i)-\sum(w^j)$, so $m$ can be balanced using the set of weights $\{w^i,w^j\}$

Comment: @Vepir Apologies. I didn't fully appreciate your somewhat confusing (to me) notion of "offset base". I did not copy your answer. I worked out my algorithm on my own. Many questions receive responses that differ very little in the math involved, and it seems this has happened here. In comparing the two answers I feel that my formulation presented as an algorithm makes a solution to the problem for arbitrarily chosen $m,w$ more practically accessible, which perhaps adds something. So I hope you can feel :) about seeing the essence of the answer before I did.

Comment: What's the intuition behind subtracting $m \bmod w$ from $m$ and then dividing by $w$?

Comment: @icecream2727 When we write it as a combination of $w^k$'s:$$m=m_1+m_2w^1+m_3w^2+m_4w^3+\dots
$$If you look at it mod $w$, you get $m_1$. Then you subtract $m_1$ from $m$, and divide by $w$, to get:$$\frac{m-m_1}{w}=m'=m_2+m_3w^1+m_4w^2+m_5w^3+\dots
$$And we can repeat the process now on our new $m'$ to get $m_2$, and so on until $$m=0$$ Notice that this is how you covert a number $m$ to base $w$. Having digits $\{-1,0,1,\dots\}$ instead of $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ is not a problem, because we can substitute otherwise largest digit $(w-1)$ with $(-1)$ instead, since: $$(-1)\equiv(w-1)\pmod{w}$$

Comment: @Vepir I LOVE YOU